# Send Data from LAMP stack to Flutter Application

Tags: php, flutter, websocket

I have set up a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MariaDB, PHP) Server on my Raspberry PI and I'm able to use HTTP GET and PUSH Requests to get and push Data from/to the MariaDB database via php code in the local network.

**What I want to do:**

Now I want to use a second client to edit a table in the Database.
The first client should display the changes in real-time on an Flutter App.

**My Problem:**

At the Moment I can only actively request if the data has changed in the DB with a HTTP GET request so to reach real-time speed, my app has to sent multiple GET requests per seconds which is obviously not what i was going for because the APP needs to stay responsive and should use the least CPU power as possible.

**Therefore I try to send a signal from the php-Server to the flutter App. This way the Flutter-App can wait passive until the data in the DB has changed.**

**My approaches to this problem:**

I have read about *websockets* which seem to be the solution to this problem however I still have no clue how too implement it with a LAMP Stack.

Can somebody explain how websockets work and give tips on how to start the implementation with a LAMP Stack and Flutter App?

Thank you for your help,
Paul

Comment: If you are using plain PHP, you might want to try this one: https://dev.to/robertobutti/websocket-with-php-4k2c

Comment: If you are using framework, e.g. laravel, this might help https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction